# What does the while loop in this code do?

Tags: javascript

What does the while loop in this code do?

How do while loops work?

```js
let numApples = Math.random() * 10;
    
while (numApples > 0) {
    
    console.log("Giving away an apple");
    
    numApples = numApples - 1;
    
}
    
console.log("No apples remaining!");
```

Comment: For your own educational purposes, I would suggest running this JavaScript code yourself to see how it behaves.  It chooses some random number between 0 and 10, and then gives away apples until none are remaining.

Answer (score 0):

Basically in pseudocode it does the following.

```
initiate variable called numApples with a random number 0 - 10.
Then while that number is greater than zero, 
  Output a message to the console saying "Giving away an apple" then
  Subtract one from the numApples number.

Finally when the numApples becomes equal to zero 
  Output a message to the console saying "No apples remaining!"
```